# tableau/SQL when no data show 0 or string in table

Tags: sql

this is my program , and i want to show 0 when server no data

```
    select
      a.toolid ,
      a.chamber,
      b.datetime,
      b.value
   from “table1” a
   left join “table2”b
   on a.toolid = b.toolid
   where b.datetime between ‘2022-06-01’ and now()
```

i test  isnull and zn, but all can’t use

Comment: Edit your question and include sample data.

Answer (score 0):

The restrictions on the `table2` table in the `WHERE` clause should be moved to the `ON` clause of the join.  Then, use `COALESCE` to display a default value for those `table2` columns whose values are not present.

```sql
SELECT
    a.toolid,
    a.chamber,
    b.datetime,          -- can use COALESCE here too, see below
    COALESCE(b.value, 0) AS value
FROM table1 a
LEFT JOIN table2 b
    ON a.toolid = b.toolid AND
       b.datetime BETWEEN '2022-06-01' AND NOW();
```

Note that we could also use `COALESCE` on `b.datetime`, but then we would need to display a default date.  If we wanted instead to display default text, then we would have to first cast `b.datetime` to text.

Comment: but i want the date can always update and display , because in my program, if server no new data update ,my program can’t get new data so i can’t get value.